# Customize Annotation Pin in MKMapKit

Tags: xcode, dictionary, annotations, mkmapview

I'm trying to customize pins on my map working on

`-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id)annotation` method in ColonnineController class

but it doesn't work, how can I solve it?

[here's the source code](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4712155/iBo.zip)

here's method:

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id)annotation{
    static NSString * parkingAnnotationIdentifier = @"ParkingAnnotationIdentifier";
    
    if([ annotation isKindOfClass:[DisplayMap class]]){
        MKAnnotationView *annotationView=[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:parkingAnnotationIdentifier];
        if(!annotationView){
            annotationView=[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:parkingAnnotationIdentifier];
            annotationView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"parkingIcon.png"];
        }
        return annotationView;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you paste your viewForAnnotation method here rather than ask other people do download and open your code.

Comment: Thank you, made it! I didn't wrote code because i don't think it's wrong...

Comment: The next step is to explain what you mean by "but it doesn't work". Are you getting no pins or standard red pins? Are you sure viewForAnnotation is being called? have you tried setting `annotationView.title` and then tapping on a pin? (if it works you should see the title in the popup box).

Comment: Means that app gets standard red pins. I can change title or subtitle but not pin image...